# Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. - Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have the following client defined in my `IdentityServer4` project:

```
new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client_id_mobile",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            ClientSecrets = { new Secret("client_secret_mobile".Sha256()) },
             AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
            RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
            AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 0,
            IncludeJwtId = true,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,                    
                "api1",                   
                IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName
            },
            RedirectUris = new []
            {
                "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
            }
        }
```

I have added an additional `API` to the solution by following [this reference](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html)

```
[Authorize(LocalApi.PolicyName)]
[Route("localApi")]
public class LocalTestAPI : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is how I have defined my `ApiScopes` and `ApiResources`

```
 public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes => new List<ApiScope>
    {           
        new ApiScope(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName, "Identity Server Api"),           
    };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources => new List<ApiResource>
    {
         new ApiResource(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)
    };
```

I authenticate with a username and password via postman using the client details above which returns 200 along with access token:

[image]

After authenticating successfully I then try to call the additional API as outlined above by passing in the access token as bearer

[image]

however, I get the following error:

> IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator
> JWT token validation error: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: 'System.DateTime', Current time: 'System.DateTime'.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: 'System.DateTime', Current time: 'System.DateTime'.

Access_Token:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkE0QTZFN0ZEQTVFRkNDMTM4MzZEN0UxMjE0MTY5RkVDIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.VgvBLiVmdR-8NJhc_vU6OLEOQOJo3_G8Qz6jWq78-b8inxi9DsPhnO38Y76XDqNbDeeLO2k_Qwt7sBQlKUBskxNvfILr-S6mkfFRQ3_3hPASIfKBlsvdhyRPHNif6ZGEXcE93XbgW7hYjG2IdT5vjg_kKdD2qpFXDwiLGSn7nhuq3cVfVsoQ-LMjtbqDFYYKp4hSqfcs5aMNZMWj1m2zll7OoiV8bOpZ1MxA1yUNzvqPvUI-05GVtp01xECjeSwRqcEhUyzzmns7SFSOKasM7WlXBB5qd5w189le2NEf6ErjGVCxAuPL3VYCbzY7_uPlOQ70hWa6EYKqqOXAf4d3Ew

I can't seem to resolve this, can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: How have you configures your ApiScopes and ApiResources? and can you post a sample Access token? and how have you configured the authorization in the API?

Comment: The api resource is defined as shown in the link referenced, authorisation is shown in post, unless I’m misunderstanding

Comment: @ToreNestenius I've updated the question to include the ApiScopes and ApiResources along with an additional postman image showing the response back when trying to call `/localApi`, also added access token

Comment: as an experiment, you can turn of the lifetime validation and see you can get pass your problem             .AddMyJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;

Comment: Are you sure the time in the API is correct?

Comment: The API is located within the same solution, I do not have a seperate project for the API regarding .AddJwtBearer where do I add this?

Comment: How do you secure your API unless you use AddJwtBearer? (ie localapi?)

Comment: I always recomend you put the API , client and Identityserver in separate instances to better keep them apart and to better reason about who is doing what and what cookie belongs to whom

Comment: I agree with @ToreNestenius but in case still you want to keep everything in the same project then you can use `.AddLocalApiAuthentication()` extension method, you can find docs [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that sticks out is this:

```cs
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 0,
```

Are you sure you want refresh tokens to expire immediately? I see you are passing the `offline_access` scope which means the refresh token is at play. Best to disable refresh tokens or do not use this scope.

Comment: "Zero allows refresh tokens that, when used with RefreshTokenExpiration = Sliding only expire after the SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime is passed" ([docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html#additional-client-settings))